# How to pick the daily volatility component in Multiplicative Components GARCH modelling?

Tags: time-series, variance, garch, volatility

Recently I've been drawn to the rather interesting Multiplicative Components GARCH model for intraday volatility modelling, a draft paper written on it can be found [here: Chanda, Engle, Sokalska, 2005](http://repec.org/sce2005/up.8558.1107223754.pdf) and an example using `rugarch` package can be found [here](http://www.unstarched.net/2013/03/20/high-frequency-garch-the-multiplicative-component-garch-mcsgarch-model/). This example is provided by `rugarch`'s author.

Daily volatility serves as a component and generally will be used, together with diurnal volatility component, to normalise the residuals: 
$$\bar\epsilon_{t,i}^2 = \epsilon_{t,i}^2/(\sigma_ts_i)$$

$\sigma_t$ is the daily vol component,
$s_i$ is a diurnal vol pattern.

What confused me is that how much data is needed to give a daily volatility estimate.

The paper has presented an example estimation for a single stock, which has daily data since August 1985 and tick data between Jan, 1998 and June 1999.

The paper seemed to have used daily data from 1985 to a day before forecast day to estimate a daily vol component; however, the intraday volatility computation was only based on tick data (10 mins interval) from Jan 1998 to June 1999.

The `rugarch` example, whilst forecasting for a different stock, used daily data from 2000 to 2008 for daily vol estimation whereas intraday vol was computed using 1-min data from Jan 2008 to Feb 2008.

I believe in calculation we still have to slice the daily vol estimate and pick the time period that matches up with that of intraday vol.

But when it comes to estimation, why do they use such a long time period for daily vol (which seems very arbitrary to me as in how long they decided to use)? Is there a best choice (criterion) for picking the daily vol time period?